# How to save the order of a drag and drop item to the database in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using [Jquery Shapeshift](https://github.com/McPants/jquery.shapeshift) for drag and drop on some lists that i have.

I have a javascript array containing the list_id and it's position. That array is sent to my controller each time i move a list. So all i need to do is take that data and save it to the position field in my database. Each list has a position field for its order.

Below is the array that contains the list_id and it's position for each list. This is sent to my controller action called sortlists each time i drag a list into a different position.

```
Parameters: {"position"=>"[[\"list_46\",0],[\"list_45\",1],
[\"list_38\",2],[\"list_44\",3],[\"list_39\",4],[\"list_37\",5]]"}
```

So how can i take that information above and update the position field for each list.

```
def sortlists
  params[:position]
  render nothing: true
end
```

Again everything things is already setup i just need to know how to use the contents in the array to update the lists.

I have tried this and it does not work.

```
def sortlists
  params[:position].each_with_index do |id, index|
  List.where(id: id).update_all({position: index+1})
  end

  render nothing: true 
end
```

### **Edit (this is what i have right now)**

**View**

```
<div class="container listwrap">
  <% @lists.each do |list| %>
    <div class="list" data-item-id="<%= list.id %>">

       <div class="list-title"> <%= list.title %></div>

    </div>
  <% end %> 
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(function() {
  $('.listwrap').shapeshift();
  $('.listwrap').on('ss-rearranged', function(e) {
    order = [];
    $(this).children().each(function() {
      order.push([$(this).attr("data-item-id"), $(this).index() ]);
    });
    $.post('/boards/sortlists',
      {order: JSON.stringify(order)},
      function(data, status, jqXHR) {
      // This is what gets rendered from your rails controller + action
    });
  });
});
```

**Controller**

```
def sortlists
  items_to_update = JSON::parse(params[:order]).map{|item| [item[0], {position: item[1]}]}
  items_hash_to_update = items_to_update.to_h
  List.update(items_hash_to_update.keys, items_hash_to_update.values)
  render nothing: true  
end
```

**Rails Terminal each time a list is dragged**

Each time i move list it runs the sortlists method in my controller. Now as you can see in the parameters i have the list_id and then the position those are correct. Then it updates everything but the positions end up wrong. They are not updated to what the parameters say they should be. It also appears to be running everything twice and i don't know why?

```
Parameters: {"order"=>"[[\"48\",0],[\"49\",1]]"}
  Parameters: {"order"=>"[[\"48\",0],[\"49\",1]]"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  List Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 48]]
  List Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 48]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "lists" SET "position" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "lists"."id" = $3  [["position", 1], ["updated_at", "2015-09-09 01:15:27.117822"], ["id", 48]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "lists" SET "position" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "lists"."id" = $3  [["position", 1], ["updated_at", "2015-09-09 01:15:27.117822"], ["id", 48]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."board_id" = $1 AND (position = 1)  [["board_id", 11]]
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."board_id" = $1 AND (position = 1)  [["board_id", 11]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "lists" SET position = (position + 1) WHERE "lists"."board_id" = $1 AND (position >= 1) AND (position < 2 AND id != 48)  [["board_id", 11]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "lists" SET position = (position + 1) WHERE "lists"."board_id" = $1 AND (position >= 1) AND (position < 2 AND id != 48)  [["board_id", 11]]
   (13.9ms)  COMMIT
   (13.9ms)  COMMIT
  List Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 49]]
  List Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 49]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "lists" SET "position" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "lists"."id" = $3  [["position", 1], ["updated_at", "2015-09-09 01:15:27.141404"], ["id", 49]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "lists" SET "position" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "lists"."id" = $3  [["position", 1], ["updated_at", "2015-09-09 01:15:27.141404"], ["id", 49]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."board_id" = $1 AND (position = 1)  [["board_id", 11]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."board_id" = $1 AND (position = 1)  [["board_id", 11]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "lists" SET position = (position + 1) WHERE "lists"."board_id" = $1 AND (position >= 1) AND (position < 2 AND id != 49)  [["board_id", 11]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "lists" SET position = (position + 1) WHERE "lists"."board_id" = $1 AND (position >= 1) AND (position < 2 AND id != 49)  [["board_id", 11]]
   (9.0ms)  COMMIT
   (9.0ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: you are doing it the wrong way @EliteViper7777 in your second edit, you are trying to use syntax meant for `batch_create` in `batch_update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have following data sent to server / controller

```
Parameters: {"position"=>"[[\"list_46\",0],[\"list_45\",1],
[\"list_38\",2],[\"list_44\",3],[\"list_39\",4],[\"list_37\",5]]"}
```

Then there may occur problems in updating if your are not sending `ids` of corresponding items in `update` mode.. its ok for `saving`.

```
# To save the items
items_to_create = JSON::parse(params[:position]).map{|item| {list_name: item[0], order: item[1]}}
List.create(items_to_create)
```

and to `update`, its better to have `ids` of list item as well like

```
Parameters: {"position"=>"[[1,\"list_46\",0],[2,\"list_45\",1],
[3,\"list_38\",2],[4,\"list_44\",3],[5,\"list_39\",4],[6,\"list_37\",5]]"}
```

Here, the first items in the array are `ids` and

```
items_to_update = JSON::parse(params[:position]).map{|item| [item[0],{list_name: item[1], order: item[2]}]}
items_hash_to_update = items_to_update.to_h
List.update(items_hash_to_update.keys, items_hash_to_update.values)
```

For more details see
https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/01/03/updating-multiple-records-at-the-same-time-rails-activerecord/

## Edit 1

If it is what you say in comment then the original param may work,

```
Parameters: {"position"=>"[[\"list_46\",0],[\"list_45\",1],
    [\"list_38\",2],[\"list_44\",3],[\"list_39\",4],[\"list_37\",5]]"}
```

and the following code may update your data in a `batch`

```
   items_to_update = JSON::parse(params[:position]).map{|item| [item[0].split('_').last, {order: item[2]}]}
    items_hash_to_update = items_to_update.to_h
    List.update(items_hash_to_update.keys, items_hash_to_update.values)
```

## Edit 2

Sorry my fault, it should have been like

```
items_to_update = JSON::parse(params[:position]).map{|item| [item[0].split('_').last, {order: item[1]}]}
```

Comment: This is getting me on the right track. That part in the array like `list_46` the `46` is the actually id. I updated my question with the Javascript and my view. Do you know how i could get it like you are saying. I don't really need the `list_name` in the array. All i need is the `id` and `postion`.

Comment: I have updated my question. The array should be correct now. So I need to figure out how to update it.

Comment: Ok so i have updated my question i did what you said in your edit and it finds the lists but it is reseting all the positions to 0.

Comment: It was because `{order: item[2]` should be `{order: item[1]` I am just looking to make sure everything is working correctly right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89024/discussion-between-illusionist-and-eliteviper7777).

Comment: Ok something is messed up. I edit my question and posted what it is doing. It's like it's going through everything twice and there is a couple things like  position + 1 and position - 1 going on that i don't understand. When i drag a list from last to first it ends up in second and the other lists end up getting screwed up.  I need to mess around with this some more tomorrow.

Comment: I have updated my question with everything i have right now. Something in my `sortlists method` must be forcing the positions to not update correctly. I don't know if you know why or not?

Comment: Fix it. I was using acts_as_list gem and that is not zero based so i had to do  `{position: item[1] + 1}`.